# How to repair corrupted lucene index?

Tags: lucene

My server was power loss and lucene index was corrupted. I runned IndexChecker but it fail:

```
java -cp /home/dthoai/programs/paesia/checker/lucene-core-3.5.0.jar -ea:org.apache.lucene... org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex /mnt/peda/paesia/index -fix


Opening index @ /mnt/peda/paesia/index

ERROR: could not read any segments file in directory
java.io.IOException: read past EOF: MMapIndexInput(path="/mnt/peda/paesia/index/segments_ls0l")
at org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory$MMapIndexInput.readByte(MMapDirectory.java:279)
at org.apache.lucene.store.ChecksumIndexInput.readByte(ChecksumIndexInput.java:41)
at org.apache.lucene.store.DataInput.readInt(DataInput.java:84)
at org.apache.lucene.store.DataInput.readLong(DataInput.java:126)
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfo.<init>(SegmentInfo.java:202)
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:286)
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$1.doBody(SegmentInfos.java:363)
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:754)
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:593)
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:359)
at org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex.checkIndex(CheckIndex.java:327)
at org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex.main(CheckIndex.java:1007)
```

How can I repair my lucene index?

Comment: have you tried opening the index in Luke? http://www.getopt.org/luke/

Answer (score 10):

It looks like the main directory file, [segments_N](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/fileformats.html#Segments%20File)  is corrupted. This probably means that the power loss happened while a commit was running.

If this is the case, this means that there is some chance that an older segments_N file is present in your directory, and that the referenced segments are still present and valid. If there is such a file, try to remove your corrupted `segments_ls0l` file and see:

- whether Lucene manages to open the index,
- what data you are missing.

Otherwise, there are some threads one Lucene user mailing-list talking about regenerating the segments_N file.

- http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/lucene/java-user/102493
- http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/lucene/java-user/39744

Make sure to backup your directory before performing any modification.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I just had the same problem, and I removed all the corrupted segments having 0 byte in size. Now everything seems to be ok. My worry is that was it safe removing those segmens_N files although they were just 0 byte files?

Comment: I solved the problem like this; Stop ES. Enter the corrupted shard `/var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/<?>/<?>/index`. Find all empty files `ls -l -S | sort -k 5 -n | head` and remove them. Start ES again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the corrupted lucene index as Mr. jpountz's answer.

This is the error of our log:

```
> 2020-11-11 12:52:06,119 (BasicLuceneIndexer.java:87) INFO  com.softslate.commerce.businessobjects.product.BasicLuceneIndexer - Reindexing products.
> 2020-11-11 12:52:06,119 (BasicLuceneIndexer.java:59) INFO  com.softslate.commerce.businessobjects.product.BasicLuceneIndexer - Writing new index to: /app/etalaze_staging/apache-tomcat-8.0.17/webapps/jatis.etalaze.community/WEB-INF/lucene/new
> 2020-11-11 12:52:06,171 (BaseRequestProcessor.java:605) WARN  com.softslate.commerce.customer.core.BaseRequestProcessor - Exception follows: 
> org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: checksum mismatch in segments file
>   at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:248)
>   at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFileDeleter.(IndexFileDeleter.java:175)
>   at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.init(IndexWriter.java:1109)
>   at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.(IndexWriter.java:626)
>   at com.softslate.commerce.businessobjects.product.BasicLuceneIndexer.getIndexWriter(BasicLuceneIndexer.java:62)
>   at com.softslate.commerce.businessobjects.product.BasicLuceneIndexer.reindex(BasicLuceneIndexer.java:88)
>   at com.softslate.commerce.administrator.product.LuceneAddAllAction.execute(LuceneAddAllAction.java:44)
>   at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
>   at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
>   at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
>   at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at com.softslate.commerce.administrator.core.AdministratorFilter.doFilter(AdministratorFilter.java:44)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at com.softslate.commerce.customer.core.SEOFilter.doFilter(SEOFilter.java:92)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at com.softslate.commerce.customer.core.HibernateFilter.doFilter(HibernateFilter.java:75)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
>   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
>   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
>   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I want to tell you the story behind it for more understanding.
On 27 October, 2020, our office had a power loss at 11:18 am. I think it was the cause of corrupted lucene index. Maybe, there was commit failure.

Everytime we commited reindexing, it produced above error and created new segments. It reapeated over and over until 11 November, 2020. Inside the directory lucene/new, there had been 44 segements file (e.g segments_1, segments_2, segments_3, ... segments_N).

**Solution:**
I did backup on the lucene folder. Then deleted all the segements_N files except the newest segments_N file and segments.gen. I keep that two files.

Finally, the error doesn't show again. And everything works as before.