# How to fix SolrException, EOFException: read past EOF: MMapIndexInput?

Tags: magento, solr, jetty

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I'm using Magento CE 1.7.0.2 & Solr 4.6.0.

I'm integrating the solr file with my site in host.When i starts server its showing the following errors please take a look at this and tell me any thing wrong i did here,The same file is working in my local magento.

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:

    {msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Error opening new searcher,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:818)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:297)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:834)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:625)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:557)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:592)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:271)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:263)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1477)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1589)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:821)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: read past EOF: MMapIndexInput(path="/home/../solr/solr-4.6.0/example/solr/collection1/data/index/segments_wy")
    at org.apache.lucene.store.ByteBufferIndexInput.readBytes(ByteBufferIndexInput.java:101)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.ChecksumIndexInput.readBytes(ChecksumIndexInput.java:49)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.DataInput.readString(DataInput.java:190)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.DataInput.readStringStringMap(DataInput.java:219)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:367)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$1.doBody(SegmentInfos.java:404)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:843)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:694)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:400)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:741)
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.<init>(SolrIndexWriter.java:77)
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.create(SolrIndexWriter.java:64)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.createMainIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:267)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.getIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:110)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1440)
    ... 15 more
,code=500}
```

Any thing wrong i did here ?

Comment: Looks like your index might be broken. Can you try running the `checkindex` tool? [Here](http://solr.pl/en/2011/01/17/checkindex-for-the-rescue/) is a reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to repair corrupted lucene index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935177/how-to-repair-corrupted-lucene-index)